Does the low conductivity of regolith limit lunar surface radio communication?
The maximum distance of radio communication depends on the carrier wave frequency. For shortwave, carrier wave range exceeds line-of-sight by utilizing skywave (ionosphere) reflection. Medium carrier wave range is limited by line-of-sight. Long carrier wave range exceeds line-of sight by using ground wave propagation.

Ground wave is a mode of radio propagation that consists of currents
traveling through the earth. Ground waves propagate parallel to and
adjacent to the surface of the Earth, and are capable covering long
distances by diffracting around the Earth's curvature.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_wave
Short wave radio communication on the moon is hampered by the absence of ionosphere;
Line-of sight transmission is limited by the short horizon distance.
Long wave transmission is potentially hampered by the low dielectric constant of the lunar regolith, which should not support ground waves. Is this a practical issue for lunar surface radio communications ?

Wikipedia links to Handbook on Ground Wave Propagation which is interesting. I think that at very long wavelengths (and thus very low data rates, like VLF and ELF) the Moon looks like a dielectric sphere, and so it might support Whispering-gallery mode EM waves. Who knows, maybe someone has already done the calculation!

Perhaps there's something discussed along just those lines in this answer to Is long range radio communication possible on the lunar surface?
